# Unable to iterate a dictionary in django templating language

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have not been able to iterate (key and values) in a nested dictionary generated from **views.py** where

*context = { "orders_current": orders_current }*

with

*return render(request, "orders/cart.html", context)*
*orders_current* is a result from a query in **views.py**:

*orders_current = Orders.objects.values('def', 'abc', 'toppings')*

*'toppings'* is stored in the database as JSON data but converted (loads) back to a dictionary in the class method:

*def __str__(self)*

in **models.py**. I did this since I read somewhere this is a recommend way of storing a dictionary in the postgresql.

Note that *orders_current* has multiple and nested dictionaries e.g.:

< QuerySet [{'category_name': 'Regular Pizza', 'size': 'small', 'item_name': 'Cheese', 'item_price': Decimal('12.70'), 'toppings_selected': True, 'toppings': '{"Mushrooms": 1.5, "Canadian Bacon": 1.5}'}] >

The dictionary {{ *order.toppings* }} passed to the html, **cart.html** is shown to have the value (in verbatim) e.g.:

*{"Mushrooms": 1.5, "Canadian Bacon": 1.5}*

So my latest attempt to extract the topping name and the corresponding price (key, value) from the dictionary is:

```
{% for order in orders_current %}
...
<table>
  {% for name, price in order.toppings.items %}
      <tr>
          <td>{{ name }}:</td>                
          <td>${{ price }}</td>
      </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</table>
```

I got no values (name, price)from this code snippet.
Based on my web searches, I've tried almost all variations of the above and with different ways of setting up the *context* for transfer.  Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is your value that you claim is verbatim printed in the client or server? If server, can you console.log on the frontend and post the output.

Comment: It is from the client (chrome) browser.  I inserted {{ order.toppings }} in cart.html

Comment: can you try order.toppings.items.all and also just order.toppings

Comment: I've tried order.toppings and it did not work.  Without an exhaustive research and as joezeppe has pointed out, I believe the main problem is that order.toppings is a string not a dictionary.  An interesting observation is that order.toppings contain " instead of ' as a dictionary would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your queryset:

```
< QuerySet [{'category_name': 'Regular Pizza', 'size': 'small', 'item_name': 'Cheese', 'item_price': Decimal('12.70'), 'toppings_selected': True, 'toppings': '{"Mushrooms": 1.5, "Canadian Bacon": 1.5}'}] >
```

**order.toppings is a string, try to convert it to dictionary in the views:**

```
import ast 
for order in orders_current:
     order["toppings"] = ast.literal_eval(order["toppings"])
```

Here are different ways to convert string dictionary to dictionary.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-convert-string-dictionary-to-dictionary/

After you convert it, it should work in the template.

Comment: That worked!  Thank you very much for your quick and correct response.  A side note:  I need to add a try clause to pass over null values.